# Flutter Widget not correctly builded

Tags: dart, widget, flutter

I have a custom Widget called HorizontalList that receives a list and displays it horizontally.

I have made a vertical list whose rows are made of these horizontal lists.

My problem is, even if the list passed to each horizontal list is different from the others, all lines rendered are the same as if I built the widgets using the same list.

I check in the constructor of the widget itself, and the data are correct, but something goes wrong while rendering.

Widget Constructor:

```
HorizontalList(List<RestInfos> infos){


_rests = new List<RestInfos>();
_rests = infos;

print("horizontal list "+ _rests.length.toString());
if(_rests.length != 0)
 print("horizontal list 1: " + _rests.elementAt(0).name);
}
```

Widget Build:

```
child: new ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: new List <Widget>.generate(_rests.length, (int index) {

        if(_rests.length == 0) {
          //return null;
          return new Card();
        }

        print("hotizontal " + _rests.length.toString());
        print("indice "+ index.toString());
        print("nome " + _rests.elementAt(index).name);

        return new GestureDetector(

          child:
           new Card(...)
     )
```

In the main page, I try to build the widget like this:

```
 child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[

          new HorizontalList(list1),
          new HorizontalList(list2),
          new HorizontalList(list3),
          new HorizontalList(list4),
       ]
)
```

Comment: give us more information, maybe the info is the same.  add a screenshot or print the output to check if the data is different

Comment: No the info is not the same, i check before `new HorizontalList` printing the dimension of the list in a Text widget, and they are correct.
As of my code, in the constructor prints the first element of each list passed to the widget, and i get the correct element, always different.
What gets rendered is always list_4 (the last list passed)

Comment: In your listview in Horizontal list build, add shrinkWrap: true

Comment: It didn't solve anything. The problem is not the dimension of the lists, but the fact that i have 5 lists who get rendered as only the last one should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the constructor i was using was "breaking" the rendering of the website.

I tried following strictly the documentation, as it is shown [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) and changing the code to the one below:

```
class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
const HorizontalList({Key key, @required this.infoList}) : super(key: key);

final List<Infos> infoList;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
}
```

It's actually very strange, as I have used my old approach elsewhere in the app and didn't result in any problem.

Anyway, this solved my problem.